# If I git rm --cached a file, then add it to .gitignore, then checkout a commit from before the file was made, will the file be deleted from disk?

Tags: git

I had a git repository, and in it was a file called `todo.txt`, which was a list of personal things to do/learn about.
I decided that I did not want this in my **Github** repository, or my local git repository, as it was personal stuff and not related to the project. What I should have done was put it in `.gitignore` from the beginning. However, I had not done that, and I know that if you put a file in .gitignore that is currently being tracked, git does NOT untrack it. So I needed a command to remove the file from version control without deleting it. I thought `git rm --cached todo.txt` would do that. So I did that. Then I added `todo.txt to .gitignore`. Then I `committed .gitignore` to my local repository. Then, later, I did git checkout to a much earlier commit, from before I created `todo.txt`.

When I did that, `todo.txt` got deleted from my disk, and it did not come back when I went back to the commit I was on before. I was under the impression that `todo.txt` would not be deleted - that it would be unchanged as I moved between commits. Did I misunderstand something about `.gitignore` or `git rm --cached`?

Why did this happen?

Comment: I'm confused.  If that earlier commit contained `todo.txt`, then how could checking out to that earlier commit result in the file being deleted?

Comment: The earlier commit was from before I made the todo.txt

Comment: Yes, with the workflow just described when you go back in history to a revision that _had_ the file, the file should "come back" to the FS.... when you checkout a revision where it had already been deleted (or where you deleted it exactly), the file should go away from the FS.

Comment: Here's the thing: Git thinks that your branch _created_ `todo.txt` at some commit.  So, when you went back before that commit, it deleted the file, since it assumes that it wasn't there at that point.  Going back to the latest commit, it also won't come back, because you did `git rm --cached` also at some later point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: But shouldn't it not have deleted the file when I went back before the commit because the file was in .gitignore by that point?

Comment: Yes, you might expect that, but that's not what happened.  The opposite of adding the file is removing it, and that seems to be what Git decided to do.

Answer (score 0):

After the update, you are describing a different problem. In order to avoid git from removing the file, I think it's better you get a copy from one of the revisions where you had it, save it somewhere else, then rewrite the history of the branch to not have it in the history ever (even including it on the .gitignore) and then you can safely put it inside the project again knowing that git won't mess with it anymore.

Say you added the file on master~10. You could do this:

`git checkout master~10
cp my-file.txt ../ # save it outside of the project, just in case
git rm --cached my-file.txt # remove it from the commit, keep it in the project
echo my-file.txt >> .gitignore # add the file to .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit --amend --no-edit # now the file is outside of this new brach history
git cherry-pick master~10..master # replay history of the master branch
git branch -f master # put master pointer on new branch
git checkout master`

At this point the file should be on the FS, git should not care about it if you move along the history of master

Comment: Might even want to consider going back to the very first revision and add it to the .gitignore from there, actually.... up to you.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR: it's the index's fault, sort of / mostly, with a dash of `.gitignore`

As long as `todo.txt` is *in* the current commit and in the index, and you switch to a commit where `todo.txt` is *not* in the commit, Git will remove `todo.txt` from the index, and hence remove it from the work-tree too.  If that would clobber precious file data, Git will sometimes complain, but if `todo.txt` is `.gitignore`-ed, Git will feel free to remove the file anyway.

### Long

One problem here is treating "disk" as a sort of individual noun at one point and collective noun at another.  We need special words to describe the situations and actions, because Git is a *version control system* and therefore has *multiple copies* of some file whose name—at the point where we talk about files by name anyway—is `todo.txt`.<sup>1</sup>

Since Git is about storing file *content*, but file content has to be accessed *by* name, we can describe some of the file versions using the colon notation that Git provides: `git show a123456:todo.txt` shows the version of `todo.txt` that was saved with the commit whose abbreviated hash is `a123456`.  These contents are stored inside Git as *blob objects*.  Those versions are permanent—well, as permanent as the commits that contain them, anyway—and entirely unchangeable.

But of course there's also a version of that file we can access in what Git calls our *work-tree* or *working tree*, when we run `less todo.txt` or `vim todo.txt` or whatever it is that we use to access and change it.  This work-tree version is *not* stored in Git at all.  It is *not* permanent; it *is* changeable, and of course removable too.

Last, there's one more version of `todo.txt`—or rather, there is sometimes.  That version is the one that is in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*.  This index has multiple functions, but the simplest description of it is: **The index is where you (and Git) build the next commit you will make.**  All of this matters because it affects how Git handles the files in the work-tree.

We can call a committed `todo.txt` by its commit-hash-and-name: `a123456:todo.txt`.  We can call the index version of `todo.txt`, if it exists, by the name `:todo.txt`.<sup>2</sup>  We can use these names with `git show` to view the stored contents of these versions of the file.  The committed contents are frozen—unchangeable—while the index contents are changeable up until we freeze them into a new commit.  Git can't `git show` the work-tree version, but there is no need: it's just plain `todo.txt` and we can see it, and change it, with the non-Gitty computer programs we have.

---

<sup>1</sup>The question of file names is tricky.  Git has a different answer from other version control systems: many others use some sort of hidden *file identifier*, while Git has only the file's name.  Git instead does dynamic rename detection under cases that are not important here, so we get to ignore tricky questions about names, and just worry about the name `todo.txt`.  In, say, ClearCase, the file named `todo.txt` might have some other name in some other revision.

<sup>2</sup>This is also `0:todo.txt`, as the index actually has four numbered slots.  Slots 1-3 are used for merging, so we get to ignore them here.

---

#### Untracked files and ignored files

We just noted that Git makes commits from whatever is in the index / staging-area.  This means that a file that is not *currently* in Git's index won't be in the *next commit you will make.*  That's why `git rm --cached` worked: it removed the file from the *index*, without touching the one in the work-tree.  The *next* commit you made did *not* have `todo.txt` as a committed file, so if that next commit got hash ID `fedcba9`, there is no `fedcba9:todo.txt`.

Suppose, now, that you're on this new commit `fedcba9`, which does not have a `todo.txt`.  The file `todo.txt` is also not in the index (which, since you just made `fedcba9` *from* the index, has the same files in the same form as in the commit—it's just that the commit's versions are frozen forever, while the index's versions can be changed or removed).  The file `todo.txt` *is*, however, in the work-tree.

When there is a file with some name, like `todo.txt`, in the work-tree that is not in the index, this file is *untracked*.  (If the file is not in the work-tree, and is not in the index, it's just not a file at all: it's like [the man upon the stair who isn't there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigonish_(poem)).)

Git is generally fairly careful about untracked files.  If we ask Git to check out some older commit, like `a123456`, that has a `todo.txt` in it, Git is going to have to clobber our work-tree `todo.txt` while it creates an index `:todo.txt` from `a123456:todo.txt`, so that the work-tree `todo.txt` matches the index `:todo.txt` that matches `a123456:todo.txt`.  So Git will complain about this: it might *destroy* our carefully created `todo.txt`, by overwriting it with the one from `a123456`.

But, alas, Git *whines* about untracked files, constantly nagging you to `git add` them, or `git add`-ing them when you use any of the *add all the files now* operations.  Remember, `git add` just means *copy this file into the index, creating it, or overwriting whatever version was in there before.  If we don't *want* that, we can create a file named `.gitignore` and put the file's name into the `.gitignore` file.  That makes Git shut up about the file.

Alas, that *also* makes Git feel free to *clobber the file's contents* in various cases.  So if we now ask Git to check out some other commit, such as `a123456`, that has a `todo.txt` in it, Git consults our current `.gitignore` and sees that `todo.txt` is ignored and hence clobber-able.  So Git extracts `a123456:todo.txt` into `:todo.txt` (the index) and `todo.txt` (the work-tree), while making commit `a123456` the current commit.

Note that this has the side effect of replacing `.gitignore` with the one from `a123456` too, or removing `.gitignore` if it's not in `a123456`.  That's not a big deal—not really.  The important thing is that when we choose to check out `a123456`, we get `:todo.txt` in our index from `a123456:todo.txt`, and that version goes into the work-tree too.

Note how, after checking out a commit, we generally have the case where *all three active versions of any file all match.*  That is, the `HEAD` commit—whatever its hash ID—holds a frozen `todo.txt`, the index `:todo.txt` matches that committed version, and the work-tree version matches the index version.  That's sometimes important, because it means that `git status` says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`: there are no work-tree "in progress" edits to be careful about.

Now we ask Git to go back to commit `fedcba9`, e.g., by running `git checkout master` (assuming `master` currently names `fedcba9`).  Git looks at this commit, comparing it to the current `a123456` commit.  There is an `a123456:todo.txt`, but there is no `fedcba9:todo.txt`.  So Git *removes* `:todo.txt` from the index—and also *removes* `todo.txt` from the work-tree.

Since it was clean, this is not a problem.  If you want it back, even if it's `.gitignore`-d in `fedcba9`, just `git show a123456:todo.txt > todo.txt`, and now you have the work-tree file.

The real problem comes about when `todo.txt` is *not* clean.  That is, since `todo.txt` is a work-tree file, we can fire up our editor and *change* it, so that `todo.txt` does not match the nonexistent `:todo.txt` that matches the nonexistent `fedcba9::todo.txt`.  If we now ask Git to switch to `a123456`, Git would normally complain here, that the work-tree version is not clean and it is not safe to switch commits.  But if `todo.txt` is *ignored*—which it is—Git says to itself: *Oh, so it's OKAY to clobber it with the one from `a123456`!*  Git does that, and now we've lost our edited `todo.txt`, replaced with `a123456:todo.txt` which gets removed when we switch back to `todo.txt`.

#### This is a real problem, and there's no real solution

The closest thing there is to an in-work-tree solution, other than rewriting history, is to avoid listing the file in `.gitignore`.  This risks accidentally re-adding the file at some point.  The other trick is to just stop keeping the file in the work-tree at all.  That's not very satisfying, but it works.